# datatable paginator primefaces not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I'm trying to include the paginator on my datatable but it's not working, i have the table and the paginator shows but it's not working, always int page 1 !! 
this is my code :
![datatable paginator not working ][1]

```
<h:form id="form">
                <p:outputPanel id="users">
                    <p:dataTable id="usersTable" value="#{personBean.allPersons}" paginator="true" rows="4" var="person"  >
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Name" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:commandLink action="#{personBean.editPerson}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personBean.person}"
                                    value="#{person}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Age" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:commandLink action="#{personBean.editPerson}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{person.age}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personBean.person}"
                                    value="#{person}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
                <p:commandButton value="Create New User"
                    action="#{personBean.newPerson}" />
            </h:form>
```

always i have the same table, i can't move to 2

Comment: make sure if your records having more than 4.

Comment: what does it mean !! i'm a biggener, thks for your help,

Comment: In `datatable` you define the attribute no. of rows per page is 4(mean `rows=4`). May be your total no. of fetching records `less then or equal to 4`

Comment: the data in my database are 7 , (7 person in the database,) but i have only 4 person, and it's not switching ,for page 2 ,

Comment: Add new `DataTable` attribute of `paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}"` and Check it shows `(1 of 2)` . It means 1 of 2 pages.

Comment: i have now (1 of 2 ) but i can't go to the 2 page !! what should i do !!

Comment: Now modify the `paginatorTemplate` attr like this, `paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"` Lets check ..

Comment: Remove this one `{RowsPerPageDropdown}`

Comment: i changed , but it's not working, always in page 1 , blocked even i press on page 2 , (1 of 2 ) << 1 2 >>, i don't know where is the problem !! ( it should works )

Comment: Blocked means unable to click ?

Comment: yes yes, enable to click, when  i press on 2 , nothing happend !! always i have page 1 ,

Comment: I think some workaround is there, Everything was defined correctly. Really strange.

Comment: yes it is, 2 days ago it was working perfectly, but now i don't know what is the problem ,

Comment: Maybe its a JS error. Is the browser console showing you any errors?

Comment: no there is't any error in the console, i have the buton for page 1 and 2 , and when i press on buton page 2, nothing happend, always in the same page 1